# rendering html title attributes with Flask-WTForms field description

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using the render_field macro presented on the [Flask-WFT documentation page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/)  to render fields in long forms across different templates.

A field is defined like this

```
year_built = IntegerField(label='Year Built', 
             description='Year built, not the year of a major renovation.',
             validators=[validators.NumberRange(
                                    min=1700,  
                                    max=2012, 
                                    message="Between %(min)s and %(max)s")])
```

The macro looks like this...

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

In the forms themselves the individual fields are placed using...

```
{{ render_field(form.year_built, class="input text")}}
```

What I cannot figure out is a way to use the description in the field object within the part of the macro that creates the HTML field `field(**kwargs)`. I know that I can pass keywords to the render_field function but I am dealing with forms with more than 100 fields and setting the description in the forms.py and then setting it again as a title keyword in the template.html seems like unnecessary repletion. I would really like to use the macro to display a description as a title if it's there or just display the field without a title if its not.

Is there a way to add new entries to `kwargs` before the field() function runs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it was much easier than I thought...

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(title=field.description, **kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Oh my... I didn't realize that field() inside template is different than Field class inside your forms.py. In other words, I can add some attribute like 'dataforajax' (field(dataforajax='test')) and it puts it in the html. However, i'm having trouble adding 'data-for-ajax', I may have to do some javascript editing of the attributes to place the dashes ----.